# Xml parsing in android with singlemenuitem

Tags: android, android-emulator, xml-parsing

Hi i wrote one xml parsing example.here i have to get the data information from mysql database and display it in android emulator successfully.
this is my code:

```
    public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168/xcart432pro/orderdetails.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "Order"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "orderid";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "orderid";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "payment_method";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "total";


ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String Orderid= ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
            String Price = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration)).getText().toString();

            String Description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);

             in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, Orderid);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DURATION, Price);
            in.putExtra(KEY_ARTIST, Description);
            startActivity(in);                  
        }
    });     
}   
     }
```

dis is my singlemenuitem.java class is:

```
    public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

// XML node keys

static final String KEY_TITLE = "orderid";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "payment_method";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "total";
@Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String product = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DURATION);
    String login = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
    String description = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTIST);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);

    TextView lblPName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cost_label);
    TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_label);

    lblName.setText(login);

    lblPName.setText(product);
    lblDesc.setText(description);
    }


    }
```

Here i have to successfully displayed on android emulator.
but i wish to display on first page orderid and payment_method only.then it is move to next page means have to display total for that particular id.please give me solutions.how can i to do.i wish to my output is :
[image]

if i clicked 13 means that particular order total only displayed on next activity.

[image]

How is to do.please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the answer.if u need hide the "description" field by adding andorid:visibility="gone" to description label in your xml file. So that the description filed will be present in listview but it won't be visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);

         in.putExtra("KEY_TITLE", Orderid);
        in.putExtra("KEY_DURATION", Price);
        in.putExtra("KEY_ARTIST", Description);
        startActivity(in);
```

singlemenuitem.java

```
            product = getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY_TITLE");
            login = getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY_DURATION");
            description = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("KEY_ARTIST");
```